# Generate random floating value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, random

I need to generate random floating numbers between 0 and 1 in the field of attribute table for ArcGIS 10.3 version.

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E240EA484E2A459582E56871DD0BB862

Comment: @PauloRaposo That documentation is for ArcGIS Pro but the equivalent for ArcGIS Desktop is at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E240EA484E2A459582E56871DD0BB862

Comment: RND() in field calculator,vb

Comment: @FelixIP I'm not sure how *random* that actually is - When I use `rnd()`, even on different feature classes, different field types, the values are always the same

Answer (score 19):

1. In the field calculator, show Codeblock.
2. In the pre-logic script code box:

   ```py
   import random
   def randnum():
       return random.random()
   ```
3. In the expression box:

   ```py
   randnum()
   ```

[image]

Result in a new `float` field:

[image]

Comment: +1 Answers that show examples and screenshots are especially helpful.

Comment: Just importing `random` in Pre-Logic Script and adding `random.random()` to the bottom input box yields the same result. One warning though, the field calculated should be a float or double type.

Answer (score 3):

You can vary parameter in expression below, depending on what [distribution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/the-distribution-syntax-for-random-values.htm) is required:

```
def aRand():
 return arcgis.rand("Normal 2 2")
```

## ---------------------------------------

```
aRand()
```